# Issue with geography library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I want to use geography library to extract the details of the places. I am unable to install it. I installed pillow, newspaper, lxml, beautifulsoup4 and all the nltk Corpas. While installing newspaper it was giving me an error in the distribute-0.6.21 library so I installed it and after that, I am facing a below error for every module I am trying to install:

```
$ conda install newspaper

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 626, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 85, in _main
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .._vendor.auxlib.path import expand
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/path.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 45
    def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0777):
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/bin/conda", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 162, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 630, in conda_exception_handler
    return handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 620, in handle_exception
    print_unexpected_error_message(e)
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 561, in print_unexpected_error_message
    from conda.base.context import context
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .._vendor.auxlib.path import expand
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/path.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Users/palakagrawal/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 45
    def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0777):
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Please help me with above error and suggest me the way to install geography module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Python 3, you should make sure all of the packages you use are compatible with Python 3. The error you get is caused by the new octal number syntax in Python3, so the following line:

```
def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0777):
```

Should be:

```
def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0o777):
```

for Python 3. You're getting this error, as the package was not designed for Python 3.

Comment: Could you please suggest how can I solve this issue now. Even a simple cmd like conda install anaconda is not working. Please suggest

Comment: @Palak It looks like by installing the distribute package, you've got a wrong version of setuptools which is for Python 2. A simple fix will be reinstalling Anaconda.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just want to know one more thing I re-installed anaconda but Conda cmd is not working in ZSH and working good in the terminal. I update.zshrc file with a path and .bash_profile even after doing this conda command not found the error is thrown in zsh shell.

Comment: @Palak Have you tried closing and reopening the shell? Using `source ~/.bash_profile` should update the variables too.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But I am still stuck with geography library. I am not getting how do I use it.

Comment: @Palak I tried to install the geograpy library, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Python 3, and it failed to import. If you can only use this library, I suggest installing a Python 2 for this purpose. Otherwise, you have to fix the package yourself, or try to find an alternative Python3 compatible option.

Answer (score 3):

There is a python 3 version/fork,  geogra**py3** . For install instructions check https://pypi.org/project/geograpy3/

Answer (score 1):

Some additions to the accepted answer:

Indeed it is clear that `geograpy` [only supports Python 2,](https://github.com/ushahidi/geograpy/issues/4) as Kamyar suggested.

Unless the place name extraction is your *only* Python task, I'd recommend you find a way to accomplish it that works with Python 3. Choose another geography package, or if your goal is entity recognition use the `nltk` directly, which supports Python 3 (`geograpy` uses the `nltk` behind the scenes). The package `geograpy` hasn't been updated since 2014, so chances are you can find something else that meets your needs better anyway.

If you do decide to run this under Python2, create a new Anaconda environment for it with `conda create --name new_env_name python=2`. See  https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html#install-a-different-version-of-python for the details. Then you can use the Anaconda command `activate` (e.g., `. activate new_env_name`) to switch between your environments.

Comment: Thank you @alexis

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python3 use:
pip3 install geograpy3