# Problems installing geograpy with Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-newspaper, geograpy

I am trying to use the geograpy module through the Anaconda Prompt. When I run

```
pip install geograpy
```

[I get this warning that terminates the installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZsVI.png)

newspaper3k is in my `AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages` folder after I followed the instructions to install it on a non unix/linux machine but whenever I try to install geograpy I still get that error.

How to I bypass this warning as I already have the newspaper3k requirement satisfied?

Comment: What version of python is installed on your machine?

Comment: Look at the error: it says to use `pip3` for Python3. It's a problem with python2 and python3

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Comment: I understand that the error is with python2 and 3 but the thing is I already installed newspaper3k, I can even use it in my code. When I do just follow the error ad type 'pip3 install newspaper3k' it doesn't recognize pip3 and when I do 'conda install newspaper3k' which I've read is the equivalent because ,y environment is python3.6 it can't find newspaper3k in the continuum repo. I installed it through other means successfully.

Comment: with Python 3 try geograpy3 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535987/issue-with-geography-library-in-python/52741898#52741898 )

Answer (score -1):

I'm a dummy. MrJLP was correct, changing my environment to 2.7 allowed me to install with no problems.

Comment: no you are not a dummy the library should support python 3

Comment: see https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3 for a python3 compatible version